# What is a Fun Puzzle?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

What is a Fun Puzzle?

<sub>I was curious to learn what makes a puzzle Fun so that I could devote my time to only working on Fun Puzzles. With that goal in mind, I set out to make a list of Fun and Not Fun puzzles. I knew this would be a contentious topic with many opinions, so I took an informal poll and below are the results. It turns out, I didn't agree with all of the choices, for example I like Logic puzzles. But I decided not to impose my beliefs, and have passed on the list to the puzzling community.</sub>

---

If a puzzle conforms to a special rule, we call it a Fun Puzzle.
Use the survey results below to find the rule.

| Fun Puzzles ™ | Not Fun Puzzles ™ |
| --- | --- |
| NO COMPUTERS | KNOWLEDGE |
| FLAGS | PROOF |
| LATERAL THINKING | RED HERRING |
| HUMOR | UNSOLVABLE |
| FOLDING | OPEN ENDED |
| PATTERN | TILING |
| HATS | WEIGHING |
| REVERSE PUZZLING | CALCULATION PUZZLE |
| ANAGRAM | LOGIC |
| VISUAL | STORY |
| METAPUZZLE | WHAT IS A WORD |
| MUSIC | CONNECT WALL |
| NETWORK | PACKING |
| ENIGMATIC | LANGUAGE |
| BOXES | AFFIX RIDDLE |
| CHESS | CRYPTOGRAPHY |

And here is a CSV version:

```
Fun Puzzles™, Not Fun Puzzles™  
NO COMPUTERS, KNOWLEDGE  
FLAGS , PROOF  
LATERAL THINKING , RED HERRING  
HUMOR , UNSOLVABLE  
FOLDING , OPEN ENDED  
PATTERN , TILING  
HATS , WEIGHING  
REVERSE PUZZLING , CALCULATION PUZZLE  
ANAGRAM , LOGIC  
VISUAL, STORY  
METAPUZZLE , WHAT IS A WORD  
MUSIC , CONNECT WALL   
NETWORK , PACKING    
ENIGMATIC , LANGUAGE  
BOXES , AFFIX RIDDLE   
CHESS , CRYPTOGRAPHY
```

**What is the special rule that determines a Fun Puzzle?**

Hint:

> If you disagree with the poll results, feel free to swap the columns of any rows for the same answer.

Hint 2:

> If it's not clear from Hint 1, this is not a What is a Word puzzle, it is a What is a Fun Puzzle puzzle. Follow the X's and Z's

Hint 3:

> The answer to row 1 is ONE. Row 3 is lying to you.

Comment: This one is easier and not terribly creative, so I apologize in advance. I think I was just drawn to the title. I promise to work harder next time.

Comment: To confirm, this is definitely meant as an [[tag:enigmatic-puzzle]] and *not*, as is usual for this format, [[tag:pattern]] & [[tag:word-property]]?

Comment: The only thing I know for certain is that this is a Fun Puzzle

Comment: Interesting tidbit: Should you take the pill? Not sure, but this puzzle functions as a hint for that one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that in the opinion of the OP, a 'Fun Puzzle' is:

> **ONE FOUND ON THE PUZZLING STACK EXCHANGE**!

If we:

> Take the letters in each line that are **shared** by both tags - and ignore those for the line containing 'RED HERRING' (as per the hint), then we end up with the following letter set:
>
>  NOE
>  F
>  (red herring)
>  UO
>  DNO
>  NT
>  H
>  EPUZZLIN
>  G
>  S
>  TA
>  C
>  K
>  ENGA
>  XE
>  CH

These can then be:

> Split into groups of consecutive letters that can be anagrammed to make the words of the solution:
>
>  NEO / FUODN / ON / THE / PUZZLING / STACK / ENGAXECH
>
>  i.e. **ONE FOUND ON THE PUZZLING STACK EXCHANGE**!